# Adding a Github release to my maven pom.xml file

Tags: maven, github, jitpack

I need to add the following GitHub project as a dependency in my pom.xml:

https://github.com/loomchild/maligna

This project defines two maven modules: maligna and maligna-ui and I need both.

Unfortunately, it seems only the first module (maligna) is being deployed to a maven artifactory.

I tried using jitPack, as follows:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

...
<depencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.loomchild.maligna</groupId>
      <artifactId>maligna-ui</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</depencies>
```

but I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project iutools-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.iutools:iutools-core:jar:1.0.2: Failure to find com.github.loomchild.maligna:maligna-ui:jar:3.0.1 in https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Is there something I misundertand about how to use jitPack?